# nginx rewrite rule missing slash

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a thumbnail class and it accepts external hosts too. It works like this right now :

```
http://mysite.com/resize/src=http://google.com/logo.png&w=50&h=50
```

I want to make it clean url with my "resize.mysite.com" subdomain like this :

```
http://resize.mysite.com/400x200/http://google.com/logo.png
```

I almost done it with this rewrite rule :

```
rewrite ^/([^x]*)x([^/]*)/(.*)$ /resize.php?w=$1&h=$2&src=$3 last;
```

But it's sending "src" without second slash after "http:" and it causes to resize class error, like this :

```
http:/google.com/logo.png
http://google.com/logo.png (what I expect)
```

How this can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing comes in mind is that your are using somewhere in your `nginx` configuration file special directive `merge_slashes`, is it true? If yes and your are using `merge_slashes on` then all your requests with double or triple and so on slashes will comes as one slash.

Can it be a solution to your problem to set directive `merge_slashes off` ?

Comment: It worked :) I never set it before but documentation says it's default value is "on" so it causes to missing slash. Thank you.

Comment: But be carefull because `merge_slashes` work on all server configuration (so all locations per specific domain + port) and sometimes it can bring some security issues. Anyway glad I could help ;)